# Mixing Kotlin and Java code

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I want to use a `Kotlin` Android library (FotoApparat) in a `Java` Android project.

In a Kotlin code base the `whenAvailble` function gets a kotlin callback as a param, which will be called when the async operation is done.

```
val photoResult = fotoapparat.takePicture()

// Asynchronously saves photo to file
photoResult.saveToFile(someFile)

// Asynchronously converts photo to bitmap and returns the result on the main thread
photoResult
    .toBitmap()
    .whenAvailable { bitmapPhoto ->
            val imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.result)

            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmapPhoto.bitmap)
            imageView.setRotation(-bitmapPhoto.rotationDegrees)
    }
```

`whenAvailable` code can be found [here](https://github.com/Fotoapparat/Fotoapparat/blob/master/fotoapparat/src/main/java/io/fotoapparat/result/PendingResult.kt)

The equivalent java implementation would be: (Previously the library was written in java)

```
fotoApparat.takePicture().
                    toPendingResult().
                    whenAvailable( /* some sort of call back */);
```

How do I provide the `whenAvailable` callback from a Java code?

In previous versions of the lib, there was a Java pending result callback class which no longer available.

Comment: i dont get your question: you already posted java code, so what do you need actually?

Comment: i'll edit to make it clearer

Comment: If you use Java 8 or higher, you can use a lambda or a method reference, otherwise you need to provide an instance of your callback (e.g., an anonymous class). By the way your original question before the edit contained a possible answer, as said by @pskink

Comment: short answer: yes you can use a Kotlin library and access it from a Java class

Comment: @user2340612 the code before the edit, does not work, it used to work for v1.x - if you can get it to work, i'd love to see how.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Abreslav [said](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/java-interop-unit-closures-required-to-return-kotlin-unit/1842/3?u=tieskedh):

> Unit is a type (unlike void) and has a value (unlike Void). This enable uniform treatment of Unit when it comes to generic classes. I.e. we don’t need another two types: a function that returns something and a function that returns void. It’s all one type: a function that returns something tat may be Unit.
>
> Introducing void would pose many problems in areas like type inference, compositionality of any sort of functions, etc

So, unlike in Kotlin, in Java you need to return this value explicitly.

Your lambda needs to be:

```
fotoApparat.takePicture().
                toPendingResult().
                whenAvailable(bitmapPhoto -> {
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.result);
        return Unit.INSTANCE;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use something like this:

```
fotoApparat.takePicture().
                toPendingResult().
                whenAvailable(bitmapPhoto -> {
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.result);
        // rest of your code
});
```

Comment: maybe it's something with my project settings, but that code has a syntax error. "missing return statement" on the last line.

Comment: Is the error shown in the callback of `whenAvailable`, or in the enclosing method? From the source code you linked, the callback passed to `whenAvailable` returns `Unit` (i.e., `void`), so the error you see shouldn't be linked to that

Comment: @user2340612 the error shown in the callback provided to whenAvailable